# Vue v-for with v-if

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I found some inconsistency in the `Vue` documentation. If someone clarify this please. Looking at [v-for-with-v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if) it says it could be useful to do it. Which in my case I am in that exact situation. But now `eslint` is complaining.

So I looked at the [style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential) and its telling me to avoid this. So there is some clear contradiction.

**Question**: Is it really that bad that you should avoid it?

**My Opinion**: I don't see it as `bad`. I have quite a few use cases where this is useful.

Comment: The `v-for` and `v-if` avoidance has nothing to do with `eslint`, I suppose? That is just a guide that encourages users to adopt better ways than trying to conjoin both directives. Also, your question is extremely vague: can you give us an example how you would want to use both directives at the same time? Otherwise this question will be closed as an opinion-based question.

Comment: Official Doc: [v-for with v-if](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if)

Comment: Hi @Ric.H, this is also surely part of their [official docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential):

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Way 1:

all nodes will be rendered on every items[] change

```
<span v-for="item in items" v-if="item.shouldRender">...</span>
```

---

Way 2:

all nodes will be rendered once

```
<template v-for="item in items">
    <span v-if="item.shouldRender">...</span>
</template>
```

---

Way 3:

only filtered nodes will be rendered. Filtered list is cached.

```
<span v-for="item in computedShouldRenderItems">...</span>
```

---

I think that 'way-1' is not REALLY bad. But I prefer to avoid it.

Comment: Why would you prefer to avoid `option 1`?

Comment: 1 - docs not recommend to use it. 2 - it is harder to read. 3 - total re-render is not necessary.

Comment: `<span v-for="item, index in items" v-if="item.shouldRender">{{ index }}</span>` - which indexes do you expect to see? :)

Comment: What if you need to stop the rendering of the whole list, but can't add a parent? Can you simple do this (inline conditional)? `<span v-for="item in (showItems ? items : [])"></span>`

It works, but not sure if it's fine to use that.

Comment: @NickeManarin - that seems like a different case - whether to show all items or not. The question, answer and docs seem to refer to filtering (show item1, hide item2)