# data from child array in v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to access the data from a child array and use that in my v-if

Here is my data and my code. Any help would be great, even just links to the correct documentation.

```
<div  class='post' v-for="message in messages"  v-if='["Food","Featured"].includes(tag) || tag === ""'>
            
            <h2>{{message.text}}</h2>

            <div v-for="category in message.categories">
              {{category.name}}
            </div> 

</div>
```

instead of

`v-if='["Food","Featured"]` I have been trying `v-if='[category in message.categories]`

Obviously that is not correct, but how do you correctly send data from a nested array UP to the `v-if`  statement?

data is here:

```
[
   {
      "text":"Featured food content",
      "categories":[
         {
            "name":"Featured",
            "ID": "189"
         },
         {
            "name":"Food",
            "ID": "190"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "text":"Featured content",
      "categories":[
         {
            "name":"Featured",
            "ID": "189"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Thank you for all the help. This my solution until I can learn how to use computed properties correctly.

```
      <template v-for="message in messages">
        <div class='post' v-if='message.categories.map(c => c.name).includes(tag) || tag === ""'>
            
            <h2>{{message.text}}</h2>

            <div v-for="category in message.categories">
              {{category.name}}
            </div> 

        </div>
      </template>
```

Comment: Does `v-if='message.categories.includes(tag)'` not work?

Comment: It gets the fully array but doesn't filter to just the *names*. 

For example, it will get:

```[ { "name": "Featured", "id": "ckfujm5vs1osw0139tnsweelb", "__typename": "Category" }, { "name": "Food", "id": "ckfrsgqnk0ehj0139brf6djv1", "__typename": "Category" } ] ```

Comment: You can do `message.categories.map(c => c.name).includes(tag)` in that case. For combining `v-for` and `v-if` however, I would suggest this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54531252/1406083

Comment: Thank you @BillyBrown. The .map can return values. 

I'll look more into the `v-for` and  `v-if` issue. I just don't want to return empty divs...

@BillyBrown your answer was the most useful, would you mind adding that as a answer. the map and the `v-for / v-if `. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that might do what you want, let me know. I couldn't tell exactly what your problem was from your code.

```
<div id="app">
  <div
    v-for="message in messages"
    v-if="messageHasCategory(message, currentCategory)"
  >
    {{message.text}}
  </div>
</div>

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    currentCategory: 'Food',
    messages: [{
      text: 'Food message',
      categories: [{
        name: "Food"
      }]
    }, {
      text: 'Featured message',
      categories: [{
        name: "Featured"
      }]
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    messageHasCategory(message, categoryName) {
      return message.categories.find(c => {
        return c.name == categoryName;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Or you can combine the v-for and v-if into a single computed property like @zerbene suggests.

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="message in currentCategoryMessages">
    {{message.text}}
  </div>
</div>

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    currentCategory: 'Food',
    messages: [{
      text: 'Food message',
      categories: [{
        name: "Food"
      }]
    }, {
      text: 'Featured message',
      categories: [{
        name: "Featured"
      }]
    }]
  },
  computed: {
    currentCategoryMessages() {
      return this.messages.filter(m => {
        return m.categories.map(c => c.name).includes(this.currentCategory);
      })
    }
  },
})
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/dyllandry-the-styleful/pen/vYKEjeb

Comment: Thank you. This is so clear and useful. I was aware of using methods or computed but was not aware you could do it on the same line as a `v-for` and `v-if`. However, it also looks like you shouldn't use them together. But use a `<template v-for> <div v-if> </div> </template>`
However this is most useful for showing me how to use the methods to find and manipulate data. Thank you

Comment: Right, I've heard it's bad practice to combine a v-for with a v-if because you should be able to accomplish the same with a computer property.

Answer (score 2):

Warning: v-for and v-if not working together in Vue.js. For the v-if, you need to transform it as COMPUTED properties like

this.data is your nested data that you have declared.
In filter() you write your test.

```
computed: {
  testedValues: function () {
    return this.data.filter(i => i.categories !== '')
  }
}
```

and after you write what you want

```
<div v-for="item in testedValues">{{item}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

(This answer disregards the issue with using both `v-for` and `v-if` at the same time, which is discussed quite well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54531252/1406083)

If you want to check the category names, you can use [`.map(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on your array, which will return a new array that you can then call `.includes(tag)` on. Put this in your `v-if`:

```js
tag === "" || message.categories.map(c => c.name).includes(tag)
```

Comment: Thank you Billy. I ended up combining the two ideas, I'm not at the state of using computed values.

`
      <template v-for="message in messages">
        <div class='post' v-if='message.categories.map(c => c.name).includes(tag) || tag === ""'>
            
            <h2>{{message.text}}</h2>

            <div v-for="category in message.categories">
              {{category.name}}
            </div> 

        </div>
      </template>
`